# varChar and Char behave different on cast

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datalength

Why the output is different of this query

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(CAST('test' AS VARCHAR)), DATALENGTH(CAST('test' AS CHAR))
```

outPut:

4,30

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VarChar always adjusts to the length of the string passed. hence the output is 4.

CHAR has default length of 30 and hence the output is 30.

Answer (score 1):

Because ["When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)". But when DataLength is applied to a varchar field, it ignores trailing spaces, while for a char field the length is just the size of the field itself.